# Insight needed into python psutil output

Tags: python

I am writing a script to passively monitor the resource usage on my computer. I want to monitor disk and network IO, CPU and RAM usage. It works fine. I am now trying to parse out this information into a more human readable output. I use psutil for python 2.7 to gather the resource information. I am now trying to parse disk usage per second. I figure I will just calculate the difference in reads and write between each second to calculate the usage per second. However i'm not sure what unit of measurement psutil is using for the IO counters. Here is an example of the output from psutil.

```
{'PhysicalDrive1': iostat", "read_count=379172, write_count=1688031, read_bytes=11142501376L, write_bytes=84719621632L, read_time=1280719510L, write_time=3614153510L), 'PhysicalDrive0': iostat", "read_count=481, write_count=0, read_bytes=1713152L, write_bytes=0L, read_time=6110L, write_time=0L), 'PhysicalDrive3': iostat", "read_count=105, write_count=42, read_bytes=377344L, write_bytes=24576L, read_time=137740L, write_time=35020L), 'PhysicalDrive2': iostat", 'read_count=646025, write_count=924922, read_bytes=14357518848L, write_bytes=17206760448L, read_time=146876820L, write_time=80879980L)}
```

I see it mentions iostat which I believe is also a program in linux for monitoring disk usage. Anywho, I see read_count and write_count right off the bat. Great, but what is the unit of measurement? Disk sectors? KB? Not sure how to count it. Also after that I have read_bytes and write_bytes, I assume the measurement is bytes but each number is followed by a capital L. What does that mean? Just trying to figure out what exactly the psutil numbers are showing me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [psutils doc](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#Disks):

> Return system disk I/O statistics as a namedtuple including the
>   following attributes:
>
> - read_count: number of reads
> - write_count: number of writes
> - read_bytes: number of bytes read
> - write_bytes: number of bytes written
> - read_time: time spent reading from disk (in milliseconds)
> - write_time: time spent writing to disk (in milliseconds)

The `L` when preceded by an integer number in python means that the number is a [Python Long](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) type, which is an unlimited precision integer (as opposed to standard Python Int type, which is at least a 32-bit precision integer implemented over a C long type (actual precision can be got from `sys.maxint.bit_length()` )).